# Writing video in mp4 format with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, video

i can save the video in .avi format.but i am unable to write the video in mp4 format. i m using opencv3

```
 fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')  
 out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```

above portion of code saves the video in .avi format.

Comment: `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')`. Keep in mind that your version of ffmpeg must support libx264.

Answer (score 0):

for making mp4 videos you can

`VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')`

you can see all fourcc codecs in 
https://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php

Comment: it gives me this err..   OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000020/' ???'

Comment: What is the version of your python and OpenCV?

Comment: i am using    python 3.5 and opencv 3.1

Comment: and i m using  ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: try `*'H264'` as fourcc (run this code for install requirements `$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev`)  if it didn't work try `*'X264'` as fourcc.

Answer (score 0):

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

and I don't get any errors.

if using fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPV4'), I get

OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'

Comment: but the video is not playing in vlc or other video play ides.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://www.fourcc.org/fmp4/):

you should replace:

```
 fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```

by:

```
 fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'FMP4')
```

I tried and succeeded.